# Script tag unsuccessful

Tags: javascript, html

This works broken apart in js fiddle but when using a script tag the clock no longer works (no longer calls js). I have tried text/javascript , adding the javascript version in a script above and my latest attempt was adding language.

How do i determine how a line of javascript is suppose to be used in a script tag? Is there any way to figure out what phrase is suppose to be used in order for this to work.

It was originally made on code pen and it shows the javascript version is 1.7 there but i cannot get this to work if i use a script tag for the life of me.

```
<script language="JavaScript">/**[minimum JS only to set current time and sound the chimes]**/
(function () {
    "use strict";
    let seconds = document.getElementById("second_time"),
        munutes = document.getElementById("minute_time"),
        hours = document.getElementById("hour_time"),
        s,
        m,
        h,
        S,
        M,
        H,
        time;

    /*[set the clock to correct time and let CSS handle the rest]*/
    function windup() {
        (time = new Date()),
            (s = time.getSeconds()),
            (m = time.getMinutes()),
            (h = time.getHours()),
            (S = s * 6),
            (M = m * 6 + s / 10),
            (H = h * 30 + 0.5 * m);

        seconds.style.transform = "rotate(" + S + "deg)";
        munutes.style.transform = "rotate(" + M + "deg)";
        hours.style.transform = "rotate(" + H + "deg)";

        console.log("windup: " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
        tick.volume = chime.volume = 1;
    }
    setTimeout(windup, 0);

    /*[main visibility API function]*/
    // use visibility API to check if current tab is active or not
    let vis = (function () {
        let stateKey,
            eventKey,
            keys = {
                hidden: "visibilitychange",
                webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
                mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
                msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
            };
        for (stateKey in keys) {
            if (stateKey in document) {
                eventKey = keys[stateKey];
                break;
            }
        }
        return function (c) {
            if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
            return !document[stateKey];
        };
    })();

    /*[HTML5 Visibility API]****************************************/
    // check if current tab is active or not
    vis(function () {
        if (vis()) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // tween resume() code goes here
                windup();
                console.log("tab is visible - has focus");
            }, 300);
        } else {
            // tween pause() code goes here
            console.log("tab is invisible - has blur");
            tick.volume = chime.volume = 0.1;
        }
    });

    // check if browser window has focus
    let notIE = document.documentMode === undefined,
        isChromium = window.chrome;
    if (notIE && !isChromium) {
        // checks for Firefox and other  NON IE Chrome versions
        $(window)
            .on("focusin", function () {
                // tween resume() code goes here
                setTimeout(function () {
                    windup();
                    console.log("focus");
                }, 300);
            })
            .on("focusout", function () {
                // tween pause() code goes here
                console.log("blur");
                tick.volume = chime.volume = 0.1;
            });
    } else {
        // checks for IE and Chromium versions
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            // bind focus event
            window.addEventListener(
                "focus",
                function (event) {
                    // tween resume() code goes here
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        windup();
                        console.log("focus");
                    }, 300);
                },
                false
            );
            // bind blur event
            window.addEventListener(
                "blur",
                function (event) {
                    // tween pause() code goes here
                    console.log("blur");
                    tick.volume = chime.volume = 0.1;
                },
                false
            );
        } else {
            // bind focus event
            window.attachEvent("focus", function (event) {
                // tween resume() code goes here
                setTimeout(function () {
                    windup();
                    console.log("focus");
                }, 300);
            });
            // bind focus event
            window.attachEvent("blur", function (event) {
                // tween pause() code goes here
                console.log("blur");
                tick.volume = chime.volume = 0.1;
            });
        }
    }
    /*[end HTML5 Visibility API]************************************/

    /*[hourly and quarterly chimes]*/
    const tick = document.getElementById("tick");
    const chime = document.getElementById("chime");
    const sound_dir = "http://www.gerasimenko.com/sandbox/codepen/sounds/";

    let bell,
        tock = "tock.wav";

    tick.src = sound_dir + tock;

    function hourly_chime(n) {
        console.log("plays left: " + n);
        if (n === 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            chime.pause();
            chime.currentTime = 0;
            chime.play();
            n--;
            setTimeout(function () {
                hourly_chime(n);
            }, 3000);
        }
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        (time = new Date()),
            (s = time.getSeconds()),
            (m = time.getMinutes()),
            (h = time.getHours());

        console.log("watch: " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
        tick.play();

        if (s === 0 && (m === 15 || m === 30 || m === 45)) {
            bell = "ding-tone.wav";
            chime.src = sound_dir + bell;
            hourly_chime(m / 15);
        } else if (s === 0 && m === 0) {
            bell = "bell-japanese.wav";
            chime.src = sound_dir + bell;
            h > 12 ? (h = h - 12) : h;
            hourly_chime(h);
        }
    }, 1000);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools. Look for error messages. [This is probably a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: Probably related: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: `<script language="JavaScript">` is HTML 3.2. Modern HTML just uses `<script>`.